# 'nuget' is not recognized but other nuget commands working

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I am trying to create a nuget package using http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory
as a reference.
My Package Manger Console in Visual Studio is not allowing me to use the 'nuget' command.
I am able to 'Get-help nuguet' and it displays:

The following NuGet cmdlets are included.

```
    Cmdlet                  Description
    ------------------      ----------------------------------------------
    Get-Package             Gets the set of packages available from the package source.

    Install-Package         Installs a package and its dependencies into the project.

    Uninstall-Package       Uninstalls a package. If other packages depend on this package, 
                            the command will fail unless the –Force option is specified.

    Update-Package          Updates a package and its dependencies to a newer version.

    Add-BindingRedirect     Examines all assemblies within the output path for a project
                            and adds binding redirects to the application (or web) 
                            configuration file where necessary.

    Get-Project             Returns a reference to the DTE (Development Tools Environment) 
                            for the specified project. If none is specifed, returns the 
                            default project selected in the Package Manager Console.

    Open-PackagePage        Open the browser pointing to ProjectUrl, LicenseUrl or 
                            ReportAbuseUrl of the specified package.

    Register-TabExpansion   Registers a tab expansion for the parameters of a command.
```

- However, whenever I start off commands with nuget is gives :

The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try ag
ain.

At line:1 char:6
 + nuget <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nuget:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have tried the following solutions:

1>closing down all items and restarting

2> uninstalling and reinstalling

3>creating a powershell profile file (this didn't exist before and this actually broke everything)

The problem started to appear after I upgraded my Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate trial version to registered. I had originally had the VS 12 Pro installed. I don't know if that really has anything to do with it but I noticed that others that had similar problems have vs 10 and 12 installed.

My question is "does anyone know what else to try?" My theory is that the path to the nuget command is missing but I cannot find how to configure the paths the package manager console uses and I am not sure where the cmdlet nuget is actually stored.

Updated---tried downloading the command line tool as suggested below. This lead to  nothing working again. I tried to uninstall and now I have a item in vs2010 extentions for nuget that doesn't have a install or unistall button enabled. This leads me to believe that it has to do with extensions installed via 2010 and 2012 that has a part in my little drama. If anyone also knows how to nuke an uninstallable extension, please advise also but I will try another question for that.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled and have you tried running visual studio as administrator to unintsall the extension?

Comment: Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine is the correct answer.

Comment: @live-love the OP is trying to create a package, not install a package

Comment: This might help - [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65625105/5714042)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can also try setting the system variable path to the location of your nuget exe and restarting VS.

1. Open your system `PATH` variable and add the location of your nuget.exe (for me this is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Visual Studio 2013`)
2. Restart Visual Studio

I would have posted this as a comment to your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059577/2038222) @done_merson but I didn't have the required reputation to do that.

Answer (score 184):

Nuget.exe is placed at `.nuget` folder of your project. It can't be executed directly in Package Manager Console, but is executed by Powershell commands because these commands build custom path for themselves.

My steps to solve are:

- Download NuGet.exe from https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/releases ([give preference for the latest release](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/releases/latest));
- Place NuGet.exe in `C:\Program Files\NuGet\Visual Studio 2012` (or your VS version);
- Add `C:\Program Files\NuGet\Visual Studio 2012` (or your VS version) in PATH environment variable <del>(see http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html as a How-to)</del> ([instructions here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)).
- Close and open Visual Studio.

---

**Update**

NuGet can be easily installed in your project using the following command:

> Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine

Comment: What should be entered as 'Variable name'?

Comment: I had to place nuget.exe on the same drive as where I was running the nuget command (and adjust the PATH environment variable value accordingly)

Comment: You can see the PATH environment variable by going to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings then on the System Properties window, click Advanced tab and there you will see the "Environment Variables..." button.

Under System variables group go find PATH environment variable. Then add another path by delimiting it with a semi-colon (;).

Comment: There must be some bug.... I get `Package 'NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0' already exists in project 'TimeLoop'` but when I write NuGet I just get a error that the command doesn't exist.

Comment: @Peter You can uninstall this version (apparently it was published yesterday) and [use this version instead](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine/2.8.6).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez is there a bug in 3.3 ? or does it just require VS 2015 update 1?

Comment: @Peter Apparently, yes. It didn't work for me in VS2015 without the Update 1.

Comment: `Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine` is terrible because, 1. It adds `NuGet.CommandLine` as a dependency to my project (ew!), and 2. It needs to be done separately in every project.  `npm` has a 'global install' option - does NuGet not have something similar!?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Until today, no, but this will probably change in NuGet 3.0 stable release. And then I'll have to update my answer.

Comment: Did this change in Nuget 3.0?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Have no idea. I'm not actively developing in .NET stack anymore.

Answer (score 96):

In `[Package Manager Console]` try the below

```
Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine
```

Comment: After "Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine",nuget.exe can be execute in PM.

Comment: Execute : The term 'Execute' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. VS2015

Comment: Don't type the whole "Execute ..." line. Just type: `Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine`

Comment: `Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
PM> `

Comment: Installs and then still doesn't work.

Answer (score 68):

There are much nicer ways to do it.

1. Install Nuget.Build package in you project that you want to pack. May need to close and re-open solution after install.
2. Install nuget via chocolatey - much nicer. Install chocolatey: https://chocolatey.org/, then run

   cinst Nuget.CommandLine

in your command prompt. This will install nuget and setup environment paths, so nuget is always available.

Comment: Not unless you use npm to install chocolatey

Comment: After having no luck with the other answers, this worked straight away for me. Chocolatey saved me having to do the PATH configuration manually

Comment: With the most recent Chocolatey, it is `choco install Nuget.CommandLine`

Answer (score 22):

In Visual Studio:

```
Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.
```

In PM:

```
Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine
```

Close Visual Studio and open it again.

Comment: Install-Package : Failed to add reference. The package 'NuGet.CommandLine' tried to add a framework reference to 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
  Reference unavailable.

Answer (score 20):

The nuget commandline tool does not come with the vsix file, it's a separate download

https://github.com/nuget/home

Comment: This is the most correct answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 14):

Retrieve `nuget.exe` from `https://www.nuget.org/downloads`. Copy it to a local folder and add that folder to the `PATH` environment variable.

This is will make nuget available globally, from any project.

Comment: It's just that easy. Create "c:\Nuget", then go to environment variables, double Path, Click New, put "C:\Nuget" and you're done. Doing everything is visual studio is 2010. Use the Powershell or the command line.

Comment: Visual Studio should be restarted after changing the PATH, otherwise it's not recognized.

Answer (score 13):

- Right-click on your project in **solution explorer**.
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution**.
- Search **NuGet.CommandLine** by Microsoft and Install it.
  [image: Search Nuget.CommandLine]
- On complete installation, you will find a folder named **packages** in
  your project. Go to solution explorer and look for it.
  [image: packages]
- Inside packages look for a folder named **NuGet.CommandLine.3.5.0**, here 3.5.0 is just version name your folder name will change accordingly.
  [image: nuGet COmmand Line]
- Inside **NuGet.CommandLine.3.5.0** look for a folder named **tools**.
  [image: tools]
- Inside **tools** you will get your **nuget.exe**
  [image: nuget.exe]

Comment: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))

Answer (score 10):

I got around this by finding the nuget.exe and moving to an easy to type path (c:\nuget\nuget) and then calling the nuget with this path. This seems to solve the problem.
c:\nuget\nuget at the package manager console works as expected.
I tried to find the path that the console was using and changing the environment path but was never able to get it to work in that way.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's really not more complicated than this!

Comment: Update Nov 2019 - nuget.exe is the .exe needed for Nuget command line tools (via either a Powershell or cmd console, or the Nuget Package Manager Console in VS) - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference.

If you don't have it get it here - https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps.

1. In visual studio go to Tools-> NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console
2. Run below command

   Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine
3. Close visual studio and reOpen again
4. repeat step 1
5. run your nuget command
   eg. nuget push C:\Users\syaads\Debug\Library.1.0.32.nupkg -Source Artifactory

Answer (score 3):

You can find the `nuget.exe` in your profile folder:

> C:\Users\YourProfileName\.nuget\packages\nuget.commandline\6.0.0\tools

If you want to use it gloablly, please register above path in `PATH` environment variable.

For detailed guide how to do it, please see [Add to the PATH in Windows 10](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 3):

### Update 2024,

Fastest & most simplest way is to just do from an `Admin` terminal and restart your shell.

```
winget install -e --id Microsoft.NuGet
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Download nuget.exe from https://www.nuget.org/downloads.
2. create a new folder in root of C drive e.g c:\nuget, copy the nuget.ext to nuget folder in c drive and paste.
3. Go to environmental settings.
4. Go to System Variable Section => select the variable name as Path and double click on path variable  => and click on new button in the last add c:\nuget => then apply  => save => save.

Answer (score 1):

Download the `nuget.exe` from the https://www.nuget.org/downloads.

Copy and paste the downloaded file to the relevant folder where your `.nupkg` is created.

Try to execute the command.

Comment: After attempting several answers this one did it for me