# The term 'nuget' is not recognized

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Trying to run any `nuget` command from **PM Console** and I get this error.

> nuget : The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path  was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + nuget update -self

What should the path be, when I run this command?

I saw this question and answer => ['nuget' is not recognized but other nuget commands working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056329/325521)

and based on the answer, I copied the `nuget.exe` to the folder and set path. After doing that, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

NuGet command from [PM Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) is different with [NuGet.exe CLI Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference). The command 'nuget' does not supported by the PM Console. Please check whether your NuGet command is correct first.
Besides, you can try to use other command from PM Console to verify this issue:

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable
```

If all command are not recognized, please check and update your Windows version. In the version 1511, you need to have been updated to .64 or later of the builds...otherwise you run into a powershell bug.

Then update the `NuGet VSIX`,

> Open Visual Studio -> Tools -> Extensions and Update -> Updates,

Update `Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013/2015` (note that: Restart your visual studio after update).

Comment: Updating Visual Studio 2017 fixed the issue for me