# nuget is not a recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: nuget, command-prompt

While running a batch file, I get the below error:
`nuget is not a recognized as an internal or external command` 
It's not working from command prompt. Have a look at the below screenshot.
[image: readably sized image]

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> nuget is not a recognized as an internal or external command

That because NuGet is a external command, can not be recognized by Windows in an arbitrary directory, you should type the "`NuGet`" or "`NuGet.exe`" in the path where NuGet.exe exists and if you want type it in an arbitrary directory, you should download the NuGet.exe (Not VSIX) from [NuGet.org](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) and **set the local path of `NuGet.exe` into your path environment variable.**

Comment: Make sure that you place the nuget.exe file in a high level folder like your user or it won't be accessible.

Answer (score 86):

This happens when either you are not in the directory where the nuget.exe is located or your environment variables are not set for it.

1. Make sure you have downloaded [NuGet.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).
2. Navigate to it and right click, then click on properties.
3. Copy the location of it.
4. Navigate to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.

Windows 10

5. Double click the variable Path click add new, paste in the location of the nuget.exe.
6. Restart Command Prompt and the issue should be fixed.

Other operating Systems

5. Double click the variable Path, If there is no other locations simply paste it in. If there is add a semi colon to the end of it and the paste it in.
6. Restart Command Prompt and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: Restart Command Prompt and the issue should be fixed, is important one.

Comment: Note for anyone doing this in a hurry:  the location is the path of the folder that contains nuget.exe, not the full path of nuget.exe (i.e. your location path does not have nuget.exe on the end)

Comment: The environment variable is called "Path". Maybe it's my dyslexia or maybe it's the lack of quotes, but I read step 5 at least 10 times before I understood that. Posting this for whoever is dysfunctional in the same way I am.

Answer (score 39):

Instead of using nuget.exe in your path, use .net version
`dotnet nuget`

Comment: Using this way you have to be aware of the fact that many features of the "normal" nuget are missing, like "nuget restore".

Comment: For the missing restore feature (from Nuget), try "dotnet restore" on the CLI in the solution or project folder.

Answer (score 14):

1. Download the Nuget Exe, keep it in a folder you want to. For ex : **D:\Software\Nuget**
2. Open Cmd prompt with the same path.
3. To create this .nuspec file, execute the following command in a command prompt.

   D:\Software\Nuget>Nuget.exe spec 
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

**For .NET Core / .NET 5**:

Use the command `dotnet pack`

Instead of using a `.nuspec` file you set those properties in your `.csproj` file, for example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>MyCompany.Project</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0.1</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

...

</Project>
```

With above config, running `dotnet pack` will create a file named

```
MyCompany.Project.1.0.0.1.nupkg
```

For more details and config options, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target

Comment: Hi, i have few standalone projects which are not referenced anywhere, I want to include them as well in nuget package, please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I follow this link and it work fine with me

[How to Fix “not recognized as an internal or external command” in Windows](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

just add the path of the nuget in the path variable

Answer (score 0):

1 - Installing Package:

I followed this Microsoft documentation. [Use the nuget.exe CLI in the package console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell#use-the-nugetexe-cli-in-the-console)

*Note:- This configuration is specific to a project and this adds dependency to the projects `package.config`*

2 - Installing exe:

You can also follow the below documentation, again from Microsoft to download and set the path to `nuget.exe` folder, as others in this thread has explained.
[NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference)