# PowerApps Tool Installer fails for self-hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I configured a self-hosted agent from which to do my Dynamics 365 app builds/deployments.

However, I seem to be missing something, as the PowerApps Tool installer fails:

```
Starting: PowerApps Tool Installer 
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerApps Tool Installer
Description  : PowerApps Tool Installer
Version      : 0.3.4
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Info](https://aka.ms/buildtoolsdoc)
==============================================================================
Installing PS module Microsoft.Xrm.OnlineManagementAPI - 1.2.0.1 ...
Installing PS module Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell - 2.0.61 ...
Installing PS module Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.PackageDeployment.Powershell - 3.3.0.882 ...
Installing PS module Microsoft.PowerApps.Checker.PowerShell - 1.0.12 ...

Name                           Version          Source           Summary                                               
----                           -------          ------           -------                                               
nuget                          2.8.5.208        https://onege... NuGet provider for the OneGet meta-package manager    
##[error]The package source "nuget.org" is available.
Installing nuget pkg Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools - 9.1.0.39 ...
##[error]For the search term and package name "Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools" no corresponding package was found. Use Get-PackageSource to display all available registered package sources.
Finishing: PowerApps Tool Installer
```

(had to translate the error message from German, so they might differ a bit)

Using Microsoft-hosted agents, the task succeeds.
I'm a beginner when it comes to this stuff, so can someone ELI5 what I'm missing?

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

> PowerApps Tool Installer fails for self-hosted agents

According to the error message, it seem the nuget.exe could not find the package `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools` from the `nuget.org`.  And it is still the old version `2.8.5.208`.

To resolve this issue, please try to download a new version of [nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v5.6.0/nuget.exe), save it in your local machine where your self-hosted agents installed.

Then set the local path of NuGet.exe into your path environment variable, check [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610728/nuget-is-not-a-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/45613370#45613370) for some more details.

Besides, open the `nuget.config` in the path:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
```

Update the package scource:

```
 <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Leo, thanks for your help! I did as you were told, downloaded newest nuget, put it in the agent directory top level, added it to path. Restarted pc/agent.
The task still shows nuget version 2.8.5.208 and still fails. I checked if there is any other nuget version set in PATH (user/system settings both), but that doesn't seem to be the case.
The nuget.config had the exact package source you were describing in it.I think I'm still missing something..?

Comment: Hello Leo, could you help me with this? I can't seem to figure it out on my own.