# Added nuget PATH environment variable, now packages will not restore

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I needed to create a `.nupkg` of my project, and in order to do this, I needed to install the `nuget.exe` and add it to `Environment Variables`.

I added it to the following:

**User Variables:**

- Variable: PATH
- Value: C:\Program Files\nuget

**System Variables**

- Variable: PATH
- Value: C:\Program Files\nuget

After adding the above, I opened my Visual Studio, and it will no longer restore my packages on the build.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: You may need to go to Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Settings and do the settings properly in General and Package Sources tabs..

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Under General settings, in Package Restore, both options are checked

Comment: Pls also chk Package Sources tab. It should have nuget.org &its uri path, and name & path of your own package source folder path.

Comment: Yes all is well there. Was always working, untill I added the PATH environemnt variable pointing to nuget.exe

Comment: Pls refer this SO QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056329/nuget-is-not-recognized-but-other-nuget-commands-working

Comment: How about change the nuget PATH environment variable to other folder, for example, `D:\nuget`. It works fine for me. If it still not work for you, please try to re-install the nuget package management with Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to add nuget into the path. This is not usually a required step. What exactly are you trying to achieve?